# Login time out when calling opening a new window from modal popup (ASP.NET)

Tags: c#, asp.net, modalpopupextender, window.open

I have a weird problem. I have a window, on a button click I open a modal popup (using `ModelPopupExtender`), that let's you select a few criteria and then click a submit button. On click of submit button, I open a new window (using `window.open()`) that shows the status of what happened to your submitted request. However, every time this status window is opened, it goes to the login page. I am thinking the modal popup can't pass the authentication cookie to the newly opened window, but I'm not sure. Here's my `web.config` portion:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
     <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" 
         protection="All" 
         defaultUrl="main.aspx" 
         name=".ASPAUTH"
         timeout="20"
         slidingExpiration="true"
         cookieless="UseCookies"
         requireSSL="false"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the "101010" icon to escape web.config code in order for it to show.

as far as passing session cookie, it doesn't get passed between pages. your browser passes it on every request. if you want to see exactly what is going on, install fiddler and take a look at headers being passed around. that will tell you exactly why certain window is redirecting to login.

is it possible that the confirm window you are redirecting to after modal exists on a different web server, or different virtual directory?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in ModalPopup. When you try to call window.open from some JS on ModalPopup, session and cookies will be lost - user is viewed by server as unathorized and thus why you get Login Page.

Hope it helps: https://support.microsoft.com/kb/831678?wa=wsignin1.0

They provide here a workaround (a little nasty) and speak about reproducability in IE6. However I have encountered the issue in Chrome too.